# using predict function with regression and factor data

Tags: r, predict

I am new to R and am having trouble understanding the predict function.

I have run a linear regression to predict CO2 emissions using the following formula (My data includes numeric, factor and a squared term):

I am predicting CO2 emissions using the following data -
`Period, CO2emissions, Month, Period^2.`

I have created a training and testing set of data.

I created a linear regression that works fine using the following formula

```
train3.lm = lm(training$CO2~training$Period + training$Month + training$P2)
```

I get the following output

```
Call:  
lm(formula = training$CO2 ~ training$Period + training$Month + 
training$P2)  

Residuals:  
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max   
-49.688  -6.964  -1.344   8.142  27.860   

Coefficients:  
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              6.315e+01  2.109e+00  29.939  < 2e-16 ***  
training$Period          5.220e-01  1.268e-02  41.154  < 2e-16 ***  
training$MonthAugust     3.287e+01  2.310e+00  14.232  < 2e-16 ***  
training$MonthDecember   2.406e+01  2.310e+00  10.415  < 2e-16 ***  
training$MonthFebruary   1.147e+01  2.310e+00   4.965 9.44e-07 ***  
training$MonthJanuary    2.893e+01  2.310e+00  12.526  < 2e-16 ***  
training$MonthJuly       3.299e+01  2.310e+00  14.283  < 2e-16 ***  
training$MonthJune       1.862e+01  2.310e+00   8.061 5.59e-15 ***  
training$MonthMarch      1.131e+01  2.310e+00   4.899 1.30e-06 ***  
training$MonthMay        7.241e+00  2.310e+00   3.135  0.00182 **   
training$MonthNovember   1.044e+01  2.310e+00   4.521 7.67e-06 ***  
training$MonthOctober    1.112e+01  2.310e+00   4.816 1.95e-06 ***  
training$MonthSeptember  1.535e+01  2.310e+00   6.644 7.97e-11 ***        
training$P2             -7.689e-04  2.376e-05 -32.365  < 2e-16 ***  

    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1  

    Residual standard error: 10.71 on 502 degrees of freedom  
    Multiple R-squared:  0.8591,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8554   
    F-statistic: 235.4 on 13 and 502 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I have a testing set of data (testing), but cannot figure out how to use the predict function to predict the CO2 emissions based on the output of my linear regression. I can do it in excel, because I can manually create the formula, but cannot figure out to create the predictions in R.

Once I get the values I plan to plot them with the actual values of CO2 in the test file to see how well my model predicted the data.

Any help would be most appreciated.